# PHP Convert variable to array

Tags: javascript, php

My variable like this,

```
$a = "A1|A2|A3|";
```

so how to convert php array?

to this,

```
$a=array("A1","A2","A3");
```

Comment: `$a = explode('|', $a);` It's one of the [functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) most people learn before anything else

Answer (score 4):

First, trim off the pipe at the end of your input.

```
$str = rtrim($a, '|');
```

Then, explode on the pipe.

```
$a = explode('|', $str);
```

Alternatively, do the split normally and then filter out the whitespace entries as a post-processing step.

```
$a = array_filter($a, 'strlen');
```

Comment: +1 Only correct answer on this question. Without trimming last pipe, you will get empty element in array. I don't understand how other answers has got upvote.

Answer (score 3):

Use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function.

```
$a = rtrim("|", $a);
$a = explode('|', $a);
print_r($a);
```

Comment: check @alex answer. You need to trim the last `|` or else you will get last empty element in array.

Answer (score 1):

You can do achieve what you want to this way:

```
$a = "A1|A2|A3|"; 
$a = rtrim($a, '|'); // Trimming the final |
$exploded = explode("|", $a); // Extracting the values from string.
var_dump($exploded);
```

Hope it answers your question.
Refer [***rtrim***](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) and [***explode***](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) on official documentation site for more relevant details.

Comment: +1 for trimming the last pipe and mentioning comments as well in answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$a=explode('|',$a);
```

Check this link

[explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

> **explode** — Split a string by string
>
> **Description**: array explode ( string $delimiter , string $string [, int $limit = PHP_INT_MAX ] )

Comment: check @alex answer. You need to trim the last | or else you will get last empty element in array.

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = "A1|A2|A3|";
$newA = explode("|",$a);
print_r($newA);
```

Comment: check @alex answer. You need to trim the last | or else you will get last empty element in array.

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = "A1|A2|A3|";
print_r(array_filter(explode("|", $a)));
```